# Unable to retrieve results using JPA query

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to build a Spring Boot REST API that fetches data from a MySQL db.
This is the JPA query method I have defined in my Repository code of my Spring Boot REST API application:

```
public interface WeekRepository extends CrudRepository<Week, UUID> {
           Iterable<Week> findByOriginId(UUID originId);
}
```

This is the details of the table that I want to query:

```
CREATE TABLE `week` 
  ( 
     `id`        DOUBLE NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     `due_date`  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
     `origin_id` BINARY(36) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `status`    VARCHAR(36) DEFAULT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
  )
```

I have turned on logging in my Spring Boot application as a result I can see the query generated by Hibernate looks like this:

```
SELECT week0_.id        AS id1_3_, 
       week0_.due_date  AS due_date2_3_, 
       week0_.origin_id AS origin_i3_3_, 
       week0_.status    AS status4_3_ 
FROM   week week0_ 
WHERE  week0_.origin_id = ?;
```

From the logs I can see that I am passing my parameter, origin_id in the JSON successfully through the controller to the repository code. The log print out in the console reveals that the parameter is being bound to the ? parameter as shown below:

```
2021-01-15 00:44:05.916 TRACE 44612 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [49ee49da-8e6e-45f0-a0ea-e63205077870]
```

However there is no result being returned by this query.

Can someone help me? Please do let me know if you need more information from my side. Thank you.

Comment: Could you check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629127/how-do-i-query-uuids-stored-as-binary-in-a-database-jpa-hibernate-mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

Please add below annotation to originId property to make hibernate to add necessary conversions. There seems to be some issue with UUID props for mysql

```
@Column(name = "origin_id")
@Type(type="uuid-char")
private UUID originId;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use @Query annotation in your weekRepository interface to get the desired result like this:

```
@Query(value="select * from week0 where week0_.origin_id = ?1",nativeQuery=true )
Iterable<Week> findByOriginId(UUID originId);
```

Here I assumed that week0 is the database table name, so check it and change accordingly and let me know if this works.

Comment: I have tried adding the native query but there is no results returned. I have noticed something in the log: o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BINARY] - [49ee49da-8e6e-45f0-a0ea-e63205077870] the UUID is being bound as a BINARY data. May I know how does the JPA decide on the Data Type?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
@Query(value="select * from week where origin_id = :originId", nativeQuery=true)
Iterable<Week> findByOriginId(UUID originId);
```